# Data (excel) prepping before analyzing with Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, data-analysis

Disclaimer: I'm very new to DA, like super new.

I'm working on my first project from scratch. It's not that big of a data set, it's a little bit over a thousand rows in excel, but very messy. They are arbitrarily combined from several sheets but the format is not unified. Which makes me wonder what is the data prepping process like before working in python. And is it more economically efficient to just manually clean up in excel first or it could be done in Python with less time?

I mean of course it depends on the size of the data and how skillful the analyst is. But I wanted to know what are the normal routes analysts take as in preparation, in consideration of efficiency and data integrity.

Many thanks!

Comment: This isn't really suited for SO. I would recommend reading up on data wrangling to get your answer.

Comment: [Wes McKinney "Python for Data Analysis"](https://wesmckinney.com/pages/book.html) is a gold standard place to start. Wes created pandas.

Comment: Try to ensure first that each excel sheet contains only single contiguous data table. This will enable you to parse each data table into a [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) dataframe with relative ease. Subsequently you can use pandas' built-in methods to wrangle the dataframes into your desired format/shape.